# How can I suppress Escape keypress event in Firefox WebExtension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-events, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a WebExtension in which I want to handle escape keypress event on an element. In the event handler, I have the following 2 lines that I thought would help me achieve the desired behavior.

```
escKeydownHandler = (event) => {
  if(isEscapeKey(event)) {
    // do something here
    // ...
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  }
}
```

I expect that this would not force the extension to close. And this works fine  if I load the same extension in chrome i.e. the extension does not closes. However, it does not work in Firefox. When I press escape on the element which has the above event handler attached in Firefox, the extension closes. Why am I doing wrong ? Is this any way to achieve the desired behavior ?

Comment: Firefox doesn't allow extensions to prevent Esc key in the popup. Submit a report on bugzilla if there's none already. I believe the reason is that the popup isn't closed on a click outside it in FF, which is very awkward.

Comment: "Firefox doesn't allow extensions to prevent Esc key in the popup". Is this documented somewhere. It would be really helpful if you can point me to the documentation. Also, I can see that the popup closes in FF when I click outside the extension. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Not documented, just something I came across. It doesn't close for me in Windows OS. Neither does the context menu on right click, which is irritating.

Comment: I am on Windows too. It does close for me. Anyways, I have filed the bug for escape keypress issue.

Comment: https://bugzil.la/1373175 - you might want to mention there that the report is about browserAction popup.

Comment: While this has ended up basically a bug report, when asking questions about a problem like this, please provide a [mcve]. Providing one is required for debugging questions. For Chrome extensions and Firefox WebExtensions, this almost always means providing a *manifest.json* and enough of the other files for us to be able to just copy and paste them into the identified file names to be able to duplicate the problem. You should also be specific as to what is going on. As written, we have to *guess* that your issue is in a popup.

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.